# What is the best way to target older IE browsers with PHP?

Tags: php, internet-explorer, browser

I've started using

`(preg_match('/(?i)msie [5-8]/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))`

in one of my projects, but been wondering if there are other ways to do the same thing or is this pretty much standard?

Comment: Using client-side detection by conditional HTML comments or JavaScript is generally a better solution.

Comment: if  you insist using php, take a look http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php, and php library http://browscap.org/